# add android platform to cordova project 3.0 after add tools directories

Tags: android, cordova, command-line-interface, cordova-3

Ok Im using cordova 3.0 CLI:

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"

$ cd hello

$ cordova platform add android
```

PROBLEM:

```
[Error: The command `android` failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the `android` command (inside the tools/ folder) added to your path. Output: /bin/sh: android: command not found]
```

Then:

```
$ export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/Primitivo/Dropbox/mobile/sdks/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/Primitivo/Dropbox/mobile/sdks/adt-bundle/sdk/tools
```

Again:

```
$ cordova platform add android
```

PROBLEM:

```
[Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. An unexpected error occurred: "$ANDROID_BIN" create project --target $TARGET --path "$PROJECT_PATH" --package $PACKAGE --activity $ACTIVITY >&/dev/null exited with 1
Deleting project...]
```

Then: I dont know what to do, I have java installed and ant too. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Java 6. I had the same issue, I wasn't aware Java 7 won't work with Android and downgrading to most recent Java 6 JDK, fixed it, as I remember.